# scala type parameters not resolving

Tags: scala, types, parameters, resolution

Hell Scala experts - I need your help.
I am trying to write some generic functions with type parameters, however
the type parameters are not resolving. Even simple built in types like String are
not resolving. I am using scala 2.12.1 and Intellij 2017.1

I have attached the code snippet below

```
import java.lang.String

trait hello_t
{
   def hello_meth1:String
   def hello_meth2[T]():T
}

class file_hello extends hello_t
{
   // for example String here resolves to java.lang.String
   val name:String = "test"

   override def hello_meth1 = "hello from method 1"

   //But type parameter "String" for hello_meth2 does not resolve - to java.lang.String 
   // And I get a compilation error see - below
   override def hello_meth2[String] = "Hello from method 2"

 }


object test extends App 
{
   val f1 = new file_hello

   f1.hello_meth1

   f1.hello_meth2

}

/* -- compilation error --
 Error:(19, 39) type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String("Hello from method 2")
 required: String
 override def hello_meth2[String] = "Hello from method 2"                                    ^
*/
```

Answer (score 4):

The definition of a method with a type parameter, abstract (as is the case in your `trait`) or not, mean that this method is defined for all possible types (unless you give some bound for the type, which is not the question here).

This means that, when you implement `hello_meth2[T](): T`, you should give a value of type `T` for any type, not just the one you decide.

For instance, the method `map[U](f: T => U): List[U]` in `List[T]` is a method that creates a `List[U]`, whatever the type `U` is, provided that you have a function to transform `T` values into `U` values.

In your case, when you're trying to implement `hello_meth2` in `file_hello`, you give the type parameter (which is called `T` in the `trait`) the name `String`, but it still is a type-parameter, which holds for any type, and not just `java.lang.String`.

What you're trying to do (if I understand it correctly) can be resolved in another way: what you want is not a method with a type parameter, but a trait with a type parameter. Indeed, you want your trait to have a method whose return type depends on the specific implementation of the trait, so this type should be a parameter of the trait.

```
trait hello_t[T] {
  def hello_meth1:String
  def hello_meth2():T
}

class file_hello extends hello_t[String] {
  override def hello_meth1 = "hello from method 1"
  override def hello_meth2() = "Hello from method 2"
}
```

Or, if you don't like type parameters, you can have type properties (which is more object-oriented):

```
trait hello_t {
  type T
  def hello_meth1:String
  def hello_meth2():T
}

class file_hello extends hello_t {
  type T = String
  override def hello_meth1 = "hello from method 1"
  override def hello_meth2() = "Hello from method 2"
}
```